# deleting chosen file in folder with ajax

Tags: ajax

//I am using below code I found here on Stack and it works well, but deletes only the latest image file in the folder no matter which one I select. Im trying to figure out how to delete the selected image file. Is there a solution for this?

```
<?php 

$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

echo "<table width='100%'><tr>";
foreach($images as $image) {
$imagedisplay = $dirnameforimage.basename($image);
echo '<td><img src="'.$imagedisplay.'" style="max-height:75px; max-width:150px">';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$image.'" id="delete_file" />';
echo '<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/></td>';


} ?>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function delete_image()
{
var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  
if(status==true)
{
var file = $("#delete_file").val();

$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"multimage/ImageLap.php",

data: {file:file},

success(html){alert('Deleted');},     

</script>
```

Comment: The part where you delete the file is  supposed to be in the _multimage/ImageLap.php_ file. What does this file contains ?

Comment: You're re-using `id` values in your HTML.  When you select `$("#delete_file")`, *which one* do you think it will use?  Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently re-using `id` values in your HTML, which is invalid.  So when you do this:

```
$("#delete_file").val()
```

The system has no way of knowing *which one* of those elements you're looking for.

Instead of putting the value in a hidden element and then looking for it, just pass the value directly to the function.  Something like this:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    $imagedisplay = $dirnameforimage.basename($image);
    echo '<td><img src="'.$imagedisplay.'" style="max-height:75px; max-width:150px">';
    echo '<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image(\''.$image.'\')"/></td>';
}
```

Then in your `delete_image()` function you would already have the value you need passed as a function argument and don't need to go find it:

```
function delete_image(file) {
    // just remove the "var file = ..." line, everything else stays the same
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you David!